# How to do a generic in kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a problem where I need to pass a generic in kotlin of a certain type of class

I have this method

```
 override fun fetchService(): LiveData<ApiResponse<ProductPostListing>> { // TODO mudar request type
                return service.getPosts("", "",page, per_page)
            }
```

And its overriding this:

```
@MainThread
    protected abstract fun fetchService(): LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>>
```

Yet its gives me an error. Can you help me on how to say the ApiResponse to Expect a class that as a List inside? ( I have reasons to do this so I cant just pass the list directly). thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@MainThread
protected abstract fun fetchService(): LiveData<ApiResponse<out RequestType>>
```

Then you can have an implementation of `RequestType` which has a `List` internally.